# How to review the selected item on spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

Here is my code for my spinner.. i want it to save to my database by using setText but theres no option for setting it into setText.. this is how i want it to save on my database `spinpstat.setText(student.status);`
this is how i want it to declare in my `onClick(View view)`
`student.status = spinpstat.getText.toString();`  but it gives me following error

```
   spinpstat = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
   ArrayAdapter adapterstat = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.statuslist, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapterstat.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinpstat.setAdapter(adapterstat);
    spinpstat.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            projstat = spinpstat.getSelectedItem().toString();

             spinpstat.setSelection(position);

            parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
```

this is the data i saved .. i set the spinner status in old student

[image]

but this how the data result in review of the data i saved.. my spinner instead of status is old student it set as new student which is the first value in my spinner list

[image]

any help will do.. thanks in advance..

Comment: `spinpstat.getSelectedItem().toString();` will do the trick

Comment: do you want to retrieve data from database ? or you want to save it to database? and exactly on which action your spinner not working .

Comment: i want to save it and retrieve it to my database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Spinner.setSelection` to set selected item from Spinner like:

```
spinpstat.setSelection(adapterstat.getPosition(student.status));
```

And get selected item from Spinner on `onClick` as:

```
student.status = spinpstat.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Comment: @Jeraline: hi, if this answer help in solving issue then mark it as answer.Thanks